# how to get data in a row column format from an excel file in c#.net

Tags: c#, .net

I have an excel sheet which contains data, in table like form, which first line is column names and rest are all rows. I want to insert data into a table in database. I have done everything to insert data to database except for getting data from excel sheet. I have tried following code but it gave data in sequential way no descrimination between rows and columns. But i want data like (columnname,rowdata)

This is data in excel file

```
firstname  lastname  salary  age
sasi   kiran    88000   32
ravi   kiran    92000   23
jafer  sharif   34000   45
kiran  bedi     45000   34
```

following code i have tried:

```
Excel.Application xlApp;
    Excel.Workbook xlWorkBook;
    Excel.Worksheet xlWorkSheet;
    Excel.Range range;
    string str;
    int rCnt = 0;
    int cCnt = 0;
    xlApp = new Excel.Application();
    xlWorkBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(@"D:\Copy of Macro with Radio_Test.xlsx", 0, true, 5, "", "", true, Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlPlatform.xlWindows, "\t", false, false, 0, true, 1, 0);
    xlWorkSheet = (Excel.Worksheet)xlWorkBook.Worksheets.get_Item(1);
    range = xlWorkSheet.UsedRange;

    for (rCnt = 1; rCnt <= range.Rows.Count; rCnt++)
    {
        for (cCnt = 1; cCnt <= range.Columns.Count; cCnt++)
        {
            str = (Convert.ToString((range.Cells[rCnt, cCnt] as Excel.Range).Value2));
            Console.WriteLine(str);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
```

but here i should get value like

```
console.writeline(firstname, sasi);
console.writeline(lastname, kiran);
```

etc for all values
how to modify the code to achieve the result

Comment: I was doing and thinking all the way to find a solution,it would be great if any body can provide a solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if i correctly understood your question, this code should provide expected output:

```
int rowCount = range.Rows.Count;
int colCount = range.Columns.Count;
string[] headers = new string[colCount+1];
for (cCnt = 1; cCnt <= colCount; cCnt++)
    {
        headers[cCnt]  = (Convert.ToString((range.Cells[1, cCnt] as Excel.Range).Value2));
    }

for (rCnt = 2; rCnt <= rowCount; rCnt++)
{
    for (cCnt = 1; cCnt <= colCount; cCnt++)
    {                
        str = (Convert.ToString((range.Cells[rCnt, cCnt] as Excel.Range).Value2));
        Console.Write(heasders[cCnt]);
        Console.Write(" ");
        Console.WriteLine(str);
    }
    Console.WriteLine("----------------");
}
Console.ReadLine();
```

Comment: Exception from exception from hresult 0x800a03ec is throwing in headers[cCnt]  = (Convert.ToString((range.Cells[rCnt, cCnt] as Excel.Range).Value2)); line

Comment: @peter, i updated my answer (row index should be 1 for headers, not 0)

Comment: only problem now i am facing is date is not getting in proper way.It is coming as a different data type

Answer (score 1):

Another way to do it could be to use excel interop to convert your excel file in a .CSV file. Following the [link](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/683804/How-to-Convert-Excel-to-CSV-using-Interop) is an example of the conversion process, after you load the .csv you can load the data to a set of POCO objects that map the form of the table. Hope it helps